# Runtime error in JAGS

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, winbugs

I'm attempting to do this in JAGS:

```
z[l] ~ dbeta(0.5,0.5)
y[i,l] ~ z[l]*dnorm(0,10000) + inprod(1-z[l],dnegbin(exp(eta_star[i,l]),alpha[l]))
```

(`dnorm(0,10000)` models a Dirac delta in 0: see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244660/modeling-multivariate-time-series-count-data-in-r/245179#245179) if you are interested in the model).

But I get:

```
     RUNTIME ERROR:
     Incorrect number of arguments in function dnegbin
```

But if I do this:

```
y[i,l] ~ dnegbin(exp(eta_star[i,l]),alpha[l])
```

It runs just fine. I wonder that I cannot multiply a value for a distribution, so I imagine that something like this could work:

```
z[l] ~ dbeta(0.5,0.5)
pointmass_0[l] ~ dnorm(0,10000)
y[i,l] ~ dnegbin(exp(eta_star[i,l]),alpha[l])
y_star[i,l] = z[l]*pointmass_0[l]+inprod(1-z[l],y[i,l])
```

If I run that I get:

```
ystar[1,1] is a logical node and cannot be observed
```

Comment: question now active also here: https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/45e40740/?limit=25#e770

Comment: if by the `y*` in your third line you mean to introduce a new variable (I don't think `y*` will work, try `y2` or `ystar`?) then yes, you have to do it that way. You can't just mix stochastic nodes into computations in that way.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks, I edited the y* since it's not available in JAGS. 

Is this the only way so? At that point my response variable y_star becomes a deterministic node

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: But at that point I'd get: 'ystar[2,1] is a logical node and cannot be observed'

Comment: @BenBolker cheesy or not that helps! thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking to model a zero-inflated negative binomial model. You can do this in JAGS if you use the "ones trick", an pseudo-likelihood method that can be used when the distribution of your outcome variables is not one of the standard distributions in JAGS but you can still write down an expression for the likelihood.

The "ones trick" consists of creating pseudo-observations with the value 1. These are then modeled as Bernoulli random variables probability parameter Lik/C where Lik is the likelihood of your observations and C is a large constant to ensure that Lik/C << 1.

```
data {
   C <- 10000
   for (i in 1:N) {
      one[i,1] <- 1
   }
}
model {

   for (i in 1:N) {
      one[i,1] ~ dbern(lik[i,1]/C)

      lik[i,1] <- (y[i,1]==0)*z[1] + (1 - z[1]) * lik.NB[i,1]   
      lik.NB[i,1] <- dnegbin(y[i,1], exp(eta_star[i,1]), alpha[1])
   }

   z[l] ~ dbeta(0.5,0.5)
}
```

Note that the name dnegbin is overloaded in JAGS. There is a distribution that has two parameters and a function that takes three arguments and returns the likelihood. We are using the latter.

I am thinking of adding zero-inflated versions of count distributions to JAGS, since the above construction is quote awkward for the user, whereas zero-inflated distributions are quite easy to implement internally in JAGS.

Comment: Professor, would you suggest to load the glm module to speed up computations? 

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I too would like to know a better way to handle this situation.

One cheesy solution is to add a stochastic node

```
ystarstar[i,j] ~ dnorm(ystar[i,j],10000000)
```

(i.e. a Normal distribution with a very high precision, or a Dirac delta in your terminology) to the model.